# How can I access HTTPServletRequest object in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am looking at http://wso2.org/forum/thread/10508 which explains how to get the HTTPServletRequest. It explains that if you have "org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.*" request then only you can get the HTTPServletRequest object. As described I did change the axis2.xml to change the transports and it worked. But then since "org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp." (NIO) trnasport are very fast I will be loosing the performance if I do that.

Is there any way of keeping the NIO transport handlers ("org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.") and get the HTTPServletRequest object?

I would be thankful if I can get the answer. All the authentication is done through cookies in the existing Data Services and company does not want to change that.

thanks
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. NIO transport is not a servlet and it does not support http sessions and all. But with the new wso2 server version we have upgraded the tomcat version so that even the normal http transport uses NIO underline.

I think you need to do a performance comparison and see with the latest release.